# How do I encrypt a java.util.Properties object (can be any size) using an RSA Public Key?

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa

This is the code I'm currently using. It uses the BouncyCastle Provider.

```
static
{
   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}

protected String encrypt(byte[] keyData, byte[] data) throws Exception {
   X509EncodedKeySpec keyspec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyData);
   KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
   PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(keyspec);
   Cipher rsa =  Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
   rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
   byte[] output = rsa.doFinal(data);
   String result = base64EncodeBytes(output);
   return result;
}
```

I'm currently getting a

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at Encryption.encrypt(RSAToken.java:60)
```

Comment: Using NoPadding is insecure. Use OAEP if you can, PKCS #1 padding (ver. 1.5) if you can't.

Comment: I updated it to use OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding. Thanks for the tip. This is my first venture into encryption. The data we're encrypting (license data) is not critical, but the more I learn about it the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using RSA to encrypt a lot of data is not a good practice.

The approach taken by cryptographic protocols is to generate a symmetric key, use it to encrypt the data, then encrypt that symmetric key with RSA.

This is how PGP and S/MIME work. It also makes it easy to allow multiple readers to decrypt the data—by encrypting the symmetric key for each intended recipient, rather than encrypting the entire data for each.

Comment: Is there a security reason for it not being a good practice? AFAIK the reason it's done this way is speed. BouncyCastle simply doesn't support it, doesn't mean it's not an option...

Comment: Speed, compatibility, and complexity are all good reasons not to do it this way. I don't know of any vulnerabilities to cryptanalytic methods in current practice, but this approach requires more code to be written by someone who doesn't have a deep understanding of cryptography, so it is definitely less secure. It would be better to use BouncyCastle's S/MIME or PGP libraries; using widely reviewed protocols and implementations is much safer than inventing your own.

Comment: You can not encrypt large data with RSA, I'd not say it's not "good practice" as it is not possible at all.
There is absolutely no problem in encrypting small amounts data with RSA directly.
However, the way RSA works your encrypted code will always be as long as your key, so if you have a 1024 bit key you can only encrypt 1024 byte of data (and even if encrypting 1 byte you still have a kb of data).
You can use a larger keysize but you will already guess, you are limited here.
That is why a universal approach uses RSA to encrypt a key which is then used for a symmetric encryption (like AES)

Comment: John, block ciphers have the same limitation. They transform a fixed-size block of data. However, they are designed to be fast and robust when applied to a sequence of blocks from a single logical message---this entails selecting a suitable "mode" for the cipher. You *could* do something similar with RSA, but it wouldn't work well. It would be incredibly slow, for starters. And no reputable cryptographer has wasted their time designing safe feedback modes for RSA, so it wouldn't be secure either. So, while you definitely can use ECB to encrypt a series of blocks with RSA, it's a bad idea.